# np.argsort() implementation is not found

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-ufunc

I would like to see how `numpy.argsort()` works.

1. In the documentation, the source for `numpy.argsort()` is
   `numpy.core.fromnumeric.py`. This is understandable.
   https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html
2. `core.fromnumeric.argsort()` is a bit more complicated. 
    Ignoring decorators, if `fromnumeric.argsort(arr)` returns `_wrapfunc(arr, "argsort")`, which returns `arr.argsort()`. This is not a problem. 
    Assuming `arr` is `numpy.ndarray`, it might be in `array_api.__init__.py`.
   https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py
3. `array_api.argsort()` is from `array_api._sorting_functions.argsort()`. OK.https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/array_api/__init__.py
4. `_sorting_functions.argsort()` calls `numpy.argsort()`. That is what I was looking for at first. It is circular.
   https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/array_api/_sorting_functions.py

Extra

5. In `numpy.__init__.pyi`, `numpy.argsort()` is from `core.fromnumeric`
   https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/__init__.pyi

   `1.` and `5.` are the same thing.

Are these circular references? Of course I know these work. Is `it might be in array_api.__init__.py.` in `2.` wrong? So where is the actual location of its implementation?

---

#### Background on this issue

I noticed that `np.unique` is slow when `return_index=True`. I wanted to run `np.unique` on the sorted array, but found that `np.unique` calls `np.argsort`. So I tried to find out the difference between `np.argsort` and `np.sort` and needed to know more about `np.argsort`.

Comment: Are you looking for [`array_argsort`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c#L1409) or [`PyArray_ArgSort`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c#L1419)?

Comment: @Brian Thanks a lot! That may be what I want. Can I have two additional questions?<br>
1. Is single-axis array also multiarray?
2. How is `numpy.argsort` related to those C codes?(This is the question about the basics of the NumPy and out of the scope of the original question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to see the source?  To implement it in your own `c` code project?  I don't think it will help you use it more effectively in python.  In an Ipython session I use `??`

```
In [22]: np.argsort??
...
return _wrapfunc(a, 'argsort', axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
```

OK, that's the typical case of a function passing the buck to the method.  The function version will convert the input to array if necessary, and then call the array's method.  Typically the function version has a more complete documentation, but the functionality is basically the same.

```
In [21]: arr.argsort??
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```

Usually that's the end of the story.

The other route is to click the `[source]` link on the documentation.  Here that leads to the same thing.

Notice:

```
@array_function_dispatch(_argsort_dispatcher)
```

recent versions have added this `dispatch` layer; check the release notes for more details.  In my experience that just makes searching for code harder.

The other step is to go to `github` and do a search.  Sometimes that turns up some useful bit, but often it's a wild-goose-chase.

As a user I don't need to know the "how" details. It's easy enough to read the docs, and then do some experiments if I still have questions.  Digging into the `c` code will not help be use it better.

As for your added question:

All `ndarray` objects are "multiarray", with anything from 0 to 32 dimensions.

### github

On `numpy` `github` I searched for `argsort`, and chose the most promising file, numpy/core/src/multiarray/methods.c

This has function

```
array_argsort(PyArrayObject *self,
        PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t len_args, PyObject *kwnames)
```

Skipping over code that appears to handle the input arguments, it looks the work is done in the

```
res = PyArray_ArgSort(self, axis, sortkind);
```

That appears to be defined in numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c

```
 PyArray_ArgSort(PyArrayObject *op, int axis, NPY_SORTKIND which)
 ...
 if (argsort == NULL) {
    if (PyArray_DESCR(op)->f->compare) {
        switch (which) {
            default:
            case NPY_QUICKSORT:
                argsort = npy_aquicksort;
                break;
            case NPY_HEAPSORT:
                argsort = npy_aheapsort;
                break;
            case NPY_STABLESORT:
                argsort = npy_atimsort;
                break;
   ...
   ret = _new_argsortlike(op2, axis, argsort, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

and so on  ....

None of that helps me use it any better.

Comment: `??` tracking is very helpful. I am glad to know your view that those additional layer makes hard to search codes. 
It seems quite complicated and won't help to know implementation.  Thanks at all.